# matching generic items

Tags: performance, recursion, typescript

### Hello fellow developers

I was wondering if anyone, with more understanding of javascript, is able to detect some potential flaws or performance issues with this recursive function.

It works as intended but I have the feeling that there is room for improvement.

Perhaps you can tell me better way of achieving the same functionality :)
I hope it is somewhat self explanatory because that is also something I want to achieve.

How would you optimize this recursive function?

```
type GenericItem = {
  hierarchyLevel: number;
  children: GenericItem[];
  label: string
  [key: string]: any;
};

const search = {
 value: "foo",
};

function matchGenericItemByLabel(item: GenericItem, term: string) {
  return (
    generateNameFromGenericItem(item)
      .toLowerCase()
      .normalize("NFD")
      .replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "")
      .includes(term.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD"))
  );
}

function searchGenericItemsInHierarchy(searchItems: GenericItem[]) {
  const foundItems: GenericItem[] = [];
  searchItems.forEach((el) => {
    if (matchGenericItemByLabel(el, search.value)) {
      foundItems.push(el);
    }
    foundItems.push(...searchGenericItemsInHierarchy(el.children));
  });

  return foundItems;
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/288035/revisions#rev-body-83755c0e-524b-4825-8657-0c407da4c41e) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.